# Is there a nice recurrence relation for $n^n$

Tags: recurrence-relations, recreational-mathematics

I know there is a nice equation for $n!$, but is there one for $n^n$? I was thinking you could get it with the fact $n^n=a^{n\log_an}$ but I can't seem to make the needed jump.

Edit: It was suggested by goblin to use the fact that $(n+1)^{n+1} = (n+1)(n+1)^n$ and expand with the binomial theorem. This gives $a_{n+1} = (n+1)\sum_{i=0}^n \binom n {n-i} n^i$

Which is still a little more complicated then I'd like. I'd love to have something of the form $a_{n+1}=a_nb^{f(n,b)}$ for every $b$

Comment: $a_n=\Big(\sqrt[n-1]{a_{n-1}}+1\Big)^n.$

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Real life seldom is... :-$)$ There is no *meaningful* recursive relation between $n^n$ and $(n-1)^{n-1}$.

Comment: Is there any way to prove that? If so please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the $W$ Lambert function (the inverse of $x\mapsto xe^x$) we get:

$$a_n=n^n$$
$$\ln a_n=n\ln n=\ln n e^{\ln n}$$
$$W(\ln a_n)=\ln n$$
Therefore
$$a_{n+1}=[e^{W(\ln a_n)}+1]^{e^{W(\ln a_n)}+1}$$

On the other hand, from your equation
$$(n+1)^{n+1}=n^n\,b^{f(b,n)}$$
we get
$$f(b,n)=\log_b\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^n}=\log_b(n+1)+n\log_b\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Comment: So basically it simplifies to $a_{n+1} = a_n(n+1)b^{n\log_b\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}$. Quite elegant. Especially since if my memory serves me correctly the last term converges to $e$.